# SQL 43 tables into 1 table

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery, union

just started exploaring the world of data analysis.

I have a dataset with 43 tables, all tables have same primary key.
How can i create 1 table out of the 43 that i have?

Are joins the only way to do that? UNION ALL for all tables? Any tips to make it easier and noob friendly :D.
I'm using BigQuery,
Thanks!

```
Select
AVG(duration)
from
 (SELECT
 day_of_week,
 duration,
 member_casual
 FROM
 (SELECT  started_at,
 ended_at,
 member_casual,
 DATETIME_DIFF (ended_at, started_at,minute) as duration,
 EXTRACT (DAYOFWEEK from started_at) as day_of_week
 FROM `cyclistic-406707.Trips_2020_to_2023.Trips_2023_10`)
 WHERE duration >= 0.1
 AND duration <=1440)
WHERE member_casual = "casual"
```

[table example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1A8tSRSMVZ0XCt7aTLLXUrBG3tpk9BHCtnMUIltU-ybQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: It does not make sense that they have the same primary key unless you mean that the field happens to be named `id`.

Comment: How do you want to combine them? Show us an example, with 2 or 3 tables.

Comment: @jarlh i want to make 1 table with the columns that i choose to make one big calculation instead calculating month by month. 

[table example] 
(https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1A8tSRSMVZ0XCt7aTLLXUrBG3tpk9BHCtnMUIltU-ybQ/edit?usp=sharing) - took 10 rows from 3 tables (each table contain info for 1 month)

Comment: @DavidHoelzer all the tables have unique ride id

Comment: So the 10 tables, are they just the same data but partitioned by month? (If they are then you could just import them one at a time in to BigQuery?)

Comment: Have you tried a VIEW ?

Comment: @RobKielty Yes exactly

Comment: @RobKielty I already imported the tables to biqquery
Lets say i need to calculate average ride duration for members. I wrote query to make it for each month. it takes 80 queries to calculate the average for each month and 2 user types
I want to combine all the tables, write one long query for average calculation filterying by month. so it would take me 2 queries. (added the code i wrote to original question)
Maybe i'm not explayning myself clear enouth

Comment: To have separate tables per time period is a bad idea to begin with. So make this one table in Bigquery by importing or inserting the rows from the other tables: `insert into all_trips select '202310' as month, t.* from trips_2023_10 t` etc. Thus, when a new month gets imported, the query stays the same, because the difference is just data, not structure, in other words: no additional table gets created, only rows get added to that one table.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner  Yeah, probably it's not the easies thing to begin with, especially if it your first project ever, but if its a challange - you learning more.
 Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use union to put the tables together?
You could use this for tables with same column count and data type:

```
SELECT_statement UNION SELECT_statement
```

Or, if you have different structure, you can just union the identical fields:

```
SELECT name
FROM customers_1
UNION
SELECT name
FROM customers_2;
```

Comment: If there is no overlapping data, then better use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION [DISTINCT]`. And if there is a table added every month, you'll have to change the query every month. So a better idea is probably to insert the data into a single table instead where you'd insert new data monthly.

Answer (score 0):

You need a VIEW, something like :

```
CREATE VIEW cyclistic-406707.Trips_2020_to_2023.AllTrips
AS

SELECT *
FROM cyclistic-406707.Trips_2020_to_2023.Trips_2020_01

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM cyclistic-406707.Trips_2020_to_2023.Trips_2020_02

UNION ALL

...

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM cyclistic-406707.Trips_2020_to_2023.Trips_2023_12;
```

After you can query directly the VIEW :

```
SELECT *
FROM cyclistic-406707.Trips_2020_to_2023.AllTrips
WHERE started_at BETWEEN ...
AND member_casual = "casual";
```

In add you can add column :

```
CREATE VIEW cyclistic-406707.Trips_2020_to_2023.AllTrips
AS

SELECT *, DATETIME_DIFF (ended_at, started_at,minute) as duration
FROM cyclistic-406707.Trips_2020_to_2023.Trips_2020_01

...
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for your answer 
Tryed to use UNION ALL with 3+ tables its didnt allow me to (as i understand because i didnt add  "CREATE VIEW"), just  made trips_2020_01 + trips_2020_02 as trips_2020_01_02 etc, after trips_2020_01_02 + trips_2020_03_04 etc.
Took me a little bit of time but a good experience anyway :)
Your way is much faster, thank you again, appreciate it!